# I can't use WP_Query

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I code

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),     
     'posts_per_page' => 2000, 
     'category__and' => 'No description tecnobath'

);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$contador = 0;
$productos = [];
$producto = (object) array(
    'name' => '',
    'sku' => '',
    'categories' => '',
    'price' => 0
);

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product;
    $producto['name'] = the_title();
    $producto['sku'] = $product->get_sku();
    $producto['price'] = $product->get_price();
    $producto['categories'] = $product->get_categories();
    array_push($productos, $producto);

endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); 

var_dump($productos);
```

But it's not working.

In the page where I put the shorcode get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   is_user_logged_in() in
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php:2352 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php(3230):
>   WP_Query->get_posts() #1
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php(3336):
>   WP_Query->query(Array) #2
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-content\plugins\cotizador\inc\products.php(9):
>   WP_Query->__construct(Array) #3
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-content\plugins\cotizador\cotizador.php(32):
>   include('C:\laragon\www\...') #4
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-settings.php(305):
>   include_once('C:\laragon\www\...') #5
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-config.php(76):
>   require_once('C:\laragon\www\...') #6
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-load.php(37):
>   require_once('C:\laragon\www\...') #7
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-blog-header.php(13):
>   require_once('C:\laragon\www\...') #8
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\index.php(17):
>   require('C:\laragon\www\...') #9 {main} thrown in
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php on line 2352

And in the archive location:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Query' not found in
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-content\plugins\cotizador\inc\products.php:9
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\laragon\www\cotizador\wp-content\plugins\cotizador\inc\products.php
>   on line 9
>   Blockquote

1. Plugins

   - cotizador

     - inc

       - products.php (*here is the code*)
     - views

       - cotizadorV.php
   - cotizador.php

cotizador.php

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

/* Añade los estilos */
include('inc/products.php');

function ctz_show() {

    include('views/cotizadorV.php'); }

add_shortcode( 'cotizador', 'ctz_show' );
```

cotizadorV.php

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

echo "Hola from CV";
```

Comment: Where is this code running? It sounds like you may have it set up independently so WP isn't being loaded.

Comment: I add the project structure

Comment: You say *In the page where I put the shortcode*- I don't see a shortcode defined anywhere, you just have code that will run as soon as the plugin is loaded, which will break every front and back-end page on your site. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Sorry, Sorry, I did not copy what I had done from the shortcode, I updated it

Comment: Note: A shortcode function is supposed to return text - an echo will just output somewhere too early.

Comment: And this: include('inc/products.php');  THat code is just running in the middle of the plugin files.   Are you expecting the results of that code to appear where the shortcode is?  In which case include('inc/products.php'); should  be inside function ctz-show and ctz_show should return the output.